# How to convert a timestamp into seconds (and fractions) in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, datetime

I'm trying to get some (application) performance data from a PostgreSQL database by looking at two dates in a record, subtracting them and getting the result as a number of seconds with fractions.

It seems I'm able to get a timestamp which includes hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds, or I can get just the seconds (and fractions) without e.g. the minutes or I can get a UNIX timestamp which is only seconds (without the milliseconds). Is there a convenient way to convert a timestamp to seconds+millis?

Example:

```
SELECT extract(SECOND FROM TIME '00:01:02.1234') as secs;
secs
--------
2.1234
```

I was hoping to get `62.1234` (that's `1 * 60 + 02.1234`) as the return value for overall seconds, not just the "seconds component" from the time value.

Is there an existing function to do that, or do I have to `EXTRACT` each part, multiply, and add each component together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `EPOCH`:

`SELECT extract(EPOCH FROM TIME '00:01:02.1234') as secs;  62.1234`

Comment: *facepalm* I don't know why, but I assumed that EPOCH would always give whole seconds.